# SSH and create a log file named as the machines name

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, nohup

I run a script which ssh a host and runs a java program. I use nohup and want the output and error log file name to be as hostnameoutput.log and hostnameerror.log. I can't get to run the program. I tried to save the value in a variable and append it to the log file name and tried the direct approach also.

The one below is the direct approach to create a log file which appends the machine name. What is the error here?

```
ssh $host "hostname; nohup java -cp program.jar >hostnameoutput.log 2>hostnameerror.log & "
```

Comment: there would appear to be some syntactic problems here, such as an unbalanced set of quote marks, that would prevent that from executing at all. It is hard to debug without knowing the actual line you entered. Could you replace the text with the actual line you were using?

Comment: sorry about the confusion. This is the line I executed. It did ssh and showed me the hostname. But using similar command late I try to append machine name with output.log and error.log. It does not work. 

ssh $host "`hostname`; nohup java -cp program.jar >`hostname`output.log 2>`hostname`error.log & "

Comment: Please edit your original question to reflect what you actually typed including the location of the second set of quote marks etc. you might also want to answer the question someone posed below.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you want the log file - assuming /bin/bash

creates remote logfile with remote host name:

```
ssh $host 'nohup java -cp program.jar >`hostname`output.log 2>`hostname`error.log &'
```

creates local logfile with remote host name

```
 nohup (ssh $host 'java -cp program.jar ' > ${host}.output.log 2> ${host}error.log ) &
```

I cannot honestly tell what you want,  please use this a starting point.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thanks tHis helped.

Comment: Actually the files I created were not in the present working directory which confused me. They by default goes to home directory. The syntax in the question is correct. Thanks